# Find Data for Microsoft Project in SharePoint enterprise

Tags: sharepoint, ms-project

Goal:
To view the table's data of the database for Microsoft Project from SharePoint 2010 and/or 2013 enterprise.

Problem:
Where can I find the raw data for Microsoft Project in the database? I would like see the detailed data for the project of the time, milestone etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint doesn't "know" about project management and saves the MS-Project file as one BLOB. Only Microsoft Project Server is capable of parsing MS-Project format and storing the data in a DB.

There are several free alternatives, though:

- Parse the MS-Project XML file. That's actually not that difficult.
- http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/ is a Java library for reading and writing MS-Project
- http://www.project-open.org/ includes a MS-Project import (written by myself) that stores the MS-Project structures in a PostgreSQL database.